# Configure generated Client certificate from API gateway to spring boot (mutual authentication)

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, aws-api-gateway, mutual-authentication

I am trying to **configure spring boot two way authentication with the key generated from AWS API gateway (which is .pem format with no private key in it).**

I tried to convert key from AWS API gateway into .jks format (as spring boot throwing invalid format for .pem), ended up with error "*unable to load private key*"

Would be a great help if someone could give more light on this (an article link also helpful) that help me to solve this.

attempts made - no luck:

- import autogenerated key from AWS API gateway into springboot
- convert .pem to .jks
- import .pem into spring boot application

Thanks in advance